# Convert char to lower case in J2ME without using the Character class

Tags: java, java-me, implementation, character, lowercase

I'd like to convert a `char` to lower case in a J2ME app. The usual `Character.toLowerCase()` doesn't work for an arbitrary Unicode character in J2ME, so I need some *light* API, or, preferably, a piece of code that would do so.

Thanks!

Comment: which character exactly you want to convert to lower ?  which range particularly ?

Comment: Why should I particularize? I like a general solution. *If* i did, I could look in the Unicode spec myself. I don't want to re-engineer the wheel: somebody must have written this kind of *general* code.

Comment: OK. The official doc says *it works only for latin-iso* chars. Other chars are not changed. That's all. In other words it's implemented only for ansi. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just copied some of the stuff from Java SE 1.3 and included it in my J2ME app. Generally, it's a few methods and three big arrays from the `Character` class.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the `toLowerCase()` method from `Character` in JavaSE JDK:

```
char lowerChar = (char)CharacterData.of((int)upperChar).toLowerCase((int)upperChar);
```

You can read the source code from the JDK and understand what is really done here and apply the same thing with your own classes in JME.

---

**Resources :**

- [grepcode - `Character.toLowerCase()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Character.java#Character.toLowerCase%28char%29)

Comment: This answers the question title, but not the question message.

Comment: @BalusC, I know it won't work as is in JME, I'm just saying that the best way to do this, is to look at the way this works with JSE. (Edited to make it more clear)

Comment: OK, my bad. I'll change the title. Of course, there is the possibility of porting some of the classes to j2me. It might be easier if their is nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

```
char toLowerCase(char c){
    if(c>=97 && c<=122)
        return (char) (c-32);
    else
        return c;
}
```

Comment: Perfect. But please tell me how in the world it is suppose to work with non-ASCII characters (like Ą, Ć, Ę, Ó, Ś... Not to mention Greek or Cyrillic)?

Comment: -1 the question is about unicode, your answer only deals with ascii.

Comment: This doesn't actually work, even for ASCII.  Based on the `-32`, it looks like it's only capable of converting to upper case instead!